# How to detect character formation in Text, using MSWord Add-ins?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ms-word, add-in

I have a Complex (Arabic) `Text` which consists of different formation like

Isolated, Initial, Medial & Final Form of a specific glyph for instance word **`کلک`** consists of initial **`ک`** + Medial **`ل`** + final **`ک`**

So First & Third glyphs are different formation of an Arabic Character.

Using **`Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Range.Characters`** I have access to All of the characters but First & Third character are the same character **`ک`**. Unfortunately In this especial case I need to access to Different Glyphs which are different to each other i.e **`ﻛ`** '\uFB90' and **`ک`** '\uFB8F'

Is there any solution to get different formation of a character? or get access to glyph Unicode value from a **Range**?

Any help is appriciated